R DT Datatable font is automaticaly times new roman in viewer pane in R Studio
I am using the DT package in R to render a data table. Simply, the data table that is rendered is always in times new roman when viewed in the Viewer panel, and in the browser popout, which does not look good. ggplot appears correctly as Arial in the Plot panel. How can I change the font for the datatable, or change the font for everything that is rendered in the Viewer panel in R Studio. I'm happy to use CSS, but that didn't seem to fix my problem, and I just want to understand why the default for R Studio Viewer is TNR.

See my code below:
library(DT)

summary <- read.csv('sample.csv')

DT::datatable(summary, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
  autoWidth = TRUE, 
  pageLength = 10,
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')),
  filter = list(
    position = 'top', clear = FALSE))


If I use ggplotly(), the font in the Viewer panel is back to arial again, so I think it's an issue with the DT package.

Does this answer address your problem?

Unfortunately not. I tried that as well, and it doesn't work

Even my Rmarkdown files are now coming out in Times New Roman, even if I manually set the css
